# exclude holidays in calculating networking days

Tags: sql

```
select orderdate, shipdate, ordernum
from dbo.orders
```

another table has

```
select date, workingday
from a.workdays
```

Table workdays has `workingday` field defined as either Y,N, which defined weekend and holidays as N.

I'd like to calculate the difference between `orderdate` and `shipdate` to pick out any `ordernum` with the days difference more than 5. How can i connect them together to reference. I researched online and many pp use variables unfortunately i'm not so familiar with this.

I successfully excluded weekend but don't know what to do with holidays.

```
DATEDIFF(dd, shipdate, orderdate + 1) - DATEDIFF(wk, orderdate, shipdate) * 2 - (CASE WHEN datename(dw, orderdate) = 'sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - (CASE WHEN datename(dw, shipdate) = 'saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DaysDifference
```

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code when you ask questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to solve this using a join and aggregate function:

```
select o.ordernum
from dbo.orders o
     join a.workdays w
     on a.workdays >= o.orderdate and a.workdays <= o.shipdate
where workingday = 'Y'
group by o.ordernum
having count(*) > 5
```

Comment: thanks, but what's the reasoning behind a.workdays >= o.orderdate and a.workdays <= o.orderdate?

Comment: @user3597281: That was a copy/paste error. It's corrected now.

Comment: thanks Allan but i don't think we can join a table (a.workdays) with a variable (o.orderdate)

Comment: `orderdate` isn't a column in the `orders` table?